# Answer my own question from other's suggestion

Tags: discussion

A member posted comments on a question I recently asked on DBA StackExchange. One of his comments helped me find the right answer to my own question, so I posted the answer myself.

But the user who helped me told me that "[I] should not post answer from other’s suggestions but rather Edit my question and add the answer to the question".

Here is the post:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231453/mongodb-stepdown-fails-in-a-psa-architecture/231548?noredirect=1#comment457029_231548

Is this true? Should I delete my answer and edit my question instead? What is the best thing to do in my case?

Comment: No, he is completely wrong. Never edit your question and add an answer there. What you did is correct. When the user didn't want to post an answer, then you can do it, but you should give that user credit by mentioning, that they gave the correct idea to fix the issue. Also when possible, don't just copy & paste the comment into an answer but, but enhance it with further explanation how it helped etc. (like you did in your answer, that is perfectly fine)

Comment: The duplicate has been asked by someone who posted the comment to answer the question, but it doesn't matter _who_ posted the comment and _who_ posts the corresponding answer. Just mention the author of the comment, then it is fine.

Comment: I just added a thank you note with a link to the user's profile. Thank you @Tom!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The advice you received was wrong.

Answers go in answers, [not in comments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), and certainly *not* in the question!

Indeed, if the user in question had posted their suggestion *in an answer* instead of a comment, you could have accepted it.

As it is, you did exactly the right thing by [self-answering](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and giving credit to the user who misunderstood how the site works.